# Некорректно отображается xml-макет в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

xml содержит следующий следующий код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/style_round_30_layout"
app:cardBackgroundColor="#232121"
android:padding="15dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/authorization"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="34sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/token"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:hint="@string/token"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColorHint="#B5B4B4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

При добавлении кнопки вниз к LinearLayout в разделе дизайна отображается какой-то бред, то есть кнопка (напомню, в LinearLayout) отобразилась поверх первого элемента, после перезагрузки xml файла макет вовсе отказался работать и показывает черный фон.

Также имеются следующие ошибки:

```
RenderProblem
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at 
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor656.invoke  at 
jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)   at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) Copy stack to clipboard

String Index out range: -1 
Error inflating the preview (Details)
Details: 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:55)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:51)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:47)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:324)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:369)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Я пытался решить проблему следующими действиями:

1. Перезагрузка пк и Android Studio
2. Перезагрузка Android плагинов
3. Invalidate caches
4. Пробовал создавать новый xml и вставлять туда код из старого
5. Менял устройство, тему и ориентацию
6. Reload All from Disk
7. В gradle менял зависимость implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0' на 1.3.0
8. Rebuild проекта

Код из gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dev.vk_bots"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

При этом проект нормально билдится и запускается на телефоне с нормальным отображением

[image: скрин]

На фотографии видно, как один и тот же код Android и Android Studio читают по-разному

UPD: создал новый проект, скопировал проблемный xml, та же фигня

Comment: Заполните `autofillHints`, например `autofillHints="token"`, либо уберите его вовсе.

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev, действительно проблема решилась, спасибо